# PHP MongoDB\Driver - how to request original document as return value after doing an update

Tags: php, mongodb

I have some PHP logic that updates an existing record in a mongo database.
This is what the code currently looks like:

```
    public function update_widget($new_data)
    {
            try{
                    $widget= new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
                    $widget->update(
                    ['widget_id' =>$new_data['widget_id']],
                    $new_data, 
                    ['multi'=> false, 'upsert'=>false]
                    );                  
                    $writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000);
                    $result= $this->mongo_db->manager->executeBulkWrite($this->mongo_db->db.'.testcollection', $widget);                                              
                    return $result;
            } catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException $e) {
                    var_dump($e->getWriteResult()->getWriteErrors());
            }
    }
```

Is there a way that I can request the "result" to contain a copy of the original document?
I've been reading over the PHP documentation for this driver and I haven't found thing just yet.  The older driver "MongoClient" used to provide this feature.

Thanks.

Comment: Not using Bulk Writes, since they are intended for a "bulk" purpose with "multiple" operations. You are not using them correctly anyway, and unless this actually is part of a "bulk update"  then you should use [`findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-findOneAndUpdate/) for single updates, which has the option to return the original or modified document. If this is in fact part of a "bulk update" then you are doing it wrong, and should be creating batches of instructions rather than individual calls.

Comment: Also, you are using the wrong driver `MongoDB\Driver` is a "low level" interface intended for "driver and framework authors", and not for "userland" use in general applications. So unless you are writing your own framework with "optimized" operations and a specific DSL, then you should be using the PHP-Library driver instead. An overview can be read on php.net [Achitecture Overview](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.overview.php)

Comment: @NeilLunn The architecture overview was helpful  Thanks for that.

Comment: The lesson here is to choose the correct driver. You chose the wrong one. But I actually told you that on a question you asked before.

Comment: @NeilLunn Really?  My bad.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is this library https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library, way better than the PHP driver

To obtain a copy:

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->your->collection;
$document = $collection->findOne(['widget_id' => $new_data['widget_id']]);
var_dump($document);
```

To replace:

```
$updateResult = $collection->replaceOne(
   ['widget_id' => $new_data['widget_id']],
   $new_data
);

printf("Matched %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getMatchedCount());
printf("Modified %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getModifiedCount());
```

To update:

```
$updateResult = $collection->updateOne(
   ['widget_id' => $new_data['widget_id']],
   ['$set' => ['something' => $new_data['something']]],
   ['upsert' => false]
);

printf("Matched %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getMatchedCount());
printf("Modified %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getModifiedCount());
printf("Upserted %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getUpsertedCount());
```

I hope that it helps